# How can I listing data according to last data_id on pagination

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I am use mysql for my webpage and I wanna listing data. every page listing 21 data. bottom of page if there is data that can be listed next page button is active when click it, it send the last data id to second page. every thing is normal but when i wanna go previus it is list data order by id on  all of table data.

for example:

in my sql table is have  120 data;
first page, first data id is 120, in the same page last data_id is 99. when i clikck next, it send 99 to next page and second page list data; which data is lower than 99 limit 21. then i click next again send last data_id of page and listing data_id lower than 78.

when i wanna back from third page to second page it must listing datas where data_id lower than 99 but it is listing data_id lower than 120.

how can i listing first 21 data  uppper than 78. between 99,78

i know "between" statement but there are any data can be deleted. so data ids are change

Comment: send a page number instead of an id and calculate ids on the server side

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isolved it different way. When get the data from db (if pressed prev button) inot use order by only use condition and limit. then fetching data and use array_reverse method.

```
$isPrev=false;
if(isset($_GET["prev])){
$isPrev=true;

$query=$db->prepare("Select * from table_name where id>? limit 21);
$query->bindParam(1,$_GET['prev'];  

try{
     $query->execute();
     $queryresult=$query->fetchAll();

     if($isPrev==true){
           $queryresult=array_reverse($queryresult);
     }

     foreach($queryresult as  $results){

       // write there data
      }

   }
}
```